# how to make a text randomly display at different locations in a page randomly

Tags: javascript, jquery

how to make a text randomly display at different locations in a page.

for instance:

I want the question marks blink randomly in the header. Is it possible through jquery?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is possible.  I'd recommend using `Math.random`.  Here's an example on how to do it:

```js
maxNum = 30;
setTimeout(time,700);

function time() {
  if ($('.qusetion').length > maxNum) {
    return;
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
    $("<div class='question'>?</div>")
      .appendTo(".container")
      .css({
        "left" : $(".container").width() * Math.random(),
        "top" : $(".container").height() * Math.random()
      })
      .fadeIn(500 * Math.random(), function () {
        $(this).fadeOut(500 * Math.random(), function () {
          $(this).remove();
        });
      });
  }
  setTimeout(time,500 * Math.random() + 100);
}
```

```css
.question {
  position:fixed;
  display:none;
}
.container {
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container"></div>
```

Comment: Hello Neil, Thanks for your help. Can you help me fix these question marks upto certain width and height in a page.

Comment: Updated the post, now it will only add them into container.  You can adjust the CSS however you like.  If you could mark as answer, it'd help a lot.

Comment: Thanks a ton for all your help. I am very new to programming, I highly appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I don't bring you the code but:

Javascript Math.random():

```
Math.random();
```

From 1 to 100 then u can use for % of width and height:

//returns math random from 1 to 100

```
Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
```

Now you just miss declare some `<span>` 's (absolute positioned) contained in a 100%-100% sized component in your HTML and manage them with JQuery. One way (there are more):

```
$('#elementID').css('property': 'value');
```

Something like:

```
random = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1)
$('#span').css('top', random + '%');
$('#span').css('left', random + '%');
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes that's possible. Here is the code:

```js
var randomY = Math.random()*10000 % $('header').height(),
 randomX = Math.random()*10000 % $('header').width();

$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#question').css({
    'top' : randomY,
    'left': randomX 
  });
});
```

```css
header{
  height: 500px;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
#question{
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <span id="question">?</span>
</header>
```